# Comparing two different versions of multiple jar files

Tags: java, bash

Okay, I'm going to try to make this short and sweet. I am trying to compare a large Java project with an older branch to find out what changes have been made between the two versions. I already have the `.jar` files of both versions and the folder structure is exactly the same.

I'd like to write this in a bash script but I am trying to figure out the best method to go about this because the problem is, is that the path to the jars (and the jar names itself) are not the same as each counter part. So for example...

Comparing jar file:

```
2.2.9/com.project/dns-pool/1.2.2/dns-pool.1.2.2.jar
```

to

```
trunk/com.project/dns-pool/2.7.7/dns-pool.2.7.7.jar
```

So essentially I'll need to iterate through all the folders within trunk and compare them to it's counter part.

Comment: If the path and the name were identical it would have been the same file and you would be comparing it to itself... All version control systems have `diff` (-like) command to compare brunches... If you want to compare `jar`s I would suggest you unzip them first and then use BeyondCompare to compare dir structures

Comment: What are you trying to compare between those two example files? The contents are compiled java bytecode aren't they? What do you want to do with those contents? What sort of output are you hoping to end up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to this long time back and basically did the follow a 3 steps.

1. Rename jar files to .zip and extract all class files
2. Decompile the class files from each jar separately into two folders
   (folder_dns_1_2_2 and folder_dns_2_7_7) . (search google for java decompilers
   and find something that will decompile and entire folder/sub folder
   recursively)
3. Use a comparison tool to compare the two folder. Some tools will
   recursively compare source code within sub folders and spit out a
   complete result.

This just requires finding and using the right tools for the process. I did not have to pay for any of the tools. You will find opensource tools or even shareware within a good trail period.

There maybe false positives, if the two jars were compiled by different JRE versions. But overall you should be able to identify obvious differences. With good comparison tools you will be able to "Ignore" certain differences.

I am sorry I do not have the names of the tools that I used.